# Why SQL Displays Two Rows Instead of One

Tags: mysql, sql, join, rows

Here is the Query

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.CNIC, 
   (SELECT FullName FROM Customer WHERE CNIC=o.CNIC) Customer, 
   o.Date 
FROM orders o 
JOIN ordersproduct op ON op.OrderID=o.OrderID 
WHERE o.OrderID=1;
```

Here is the result

```
1 - 15604-5566123-2 - Shaiz Mehran - 2020-09-30
1 - 15604-5566123-2 - Shaiz Mehran - 2020-09-30
```

Comment: The customer has two products

Comment: Why do you need join if you never use any of `ordersproduct` fields?

Comment: There are two products in the order.

Comment: You get a row for each matching row in `orderproduct`.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the purpose is to only show customers who has an order, but no details of the orderproduct itself you could use the following :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderID, o.CNIC, 
    (SELECT FullName FROM Customer WHERE CNIC=o.CNIC) Customer, 
    o.Date 
    FROM orders o 
    WHERE o.OrderID=1;
```

OR

```
    SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderID, o.CNIC, 
    c.Customer, o.Date 
    FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.CNIC = o.CNIC
    WHERE o.OrderID=1;
```

If this is only the start and you will show the product which the customer ordered it will show two rows as the customer has two products (orderproducts). This will return two rows with different orderproducts

```
    SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderID, o.CNIC, 
    c.Customer, o.Date op.ColumnTosShow
    FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.CNIC = o.CNIC
    INNER JOIN ordersproduct op ON op.OrderID=o.OrderID
    WHERE o.OrderID=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct Orders.OrderID, Orders.CNIC, Customer.FullName
FROM (Orders LEFT JOIN Customer ON Orders.CNIC = Customer.CNIC)
LEFT JOIN OrdersProduct ON Orders.OrderID = OrdersProduct.OrderID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting multiple rows is because an order can have multiple products . . . and you are getting one row per product.

The join to the product table seems quite unnecessary, so just use:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.CNIC, 
       (SELECT FullName FROM Customer WHERE CNIC=o.CNIC) as Customer, 
       o.Date 
FROM orders o 
WHERE o.OrderID = 1;
```

I am guessing you have a reasonable data model so there are not multiple rows in `orders` for a given id.  `SELECT DISTINCT` is not necessary.

I should add that `JOIN` is very reasonable for this query, but like this:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.CNIC, c.FullName as Customer, 
       o.Date 
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     customer c
     ON o.CNIC = c.CNIC
WHERE o.OrderID = 1;
```